# Meu Node.JS continua executando na versão antiga

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-cloud-functions

Olá, estou fazendo notificações com cloud functions e node.js, a minha versão do Node.Js é a 12 mas o deploy está sendo na 8, alguém pode me ajudar ? PS: O Google vai deixar de aceitar a versão 8.[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1):

Segundo a [documentação](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/manage-functions), basta adicionar a linha:

```
"engines": {"node": "10"}
```

No seu `package.json`

Comment: Muito obrigado pela ajuda, deu certo, valeu \0/